# Email is not verified firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Angular 9 and firebase. When a user signs up they get a verification email and the when they click it they are taken to a verification screen saying it has been verified. But they are getting an error when they do to login saying email is not verified. The page has to be reloaded for it to work.

```
onSignup(form: NgForm) {
this.submitted = true;

if (form.valid) {

  this.authService.RegisterUser(this.signup.username, this.signup.password)
  .then((res) => {
    // Do something here

    this.authService.SendVerificationMail();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/email-verification');
  }).catch((error) => {
    window.alert(error.message)
  })

}

}
```

Here is the send verification mail from the auth service.

```
SendVerificationMail() {
  this.ngFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  user.sendEmailVerification();

  });
}
```

Why is this happening and what should I do?

Comment: can you share what happens in your SendVerificationMail method?

Comment: It’s built in fire base method. It sends a verification email.

Comment: Are you sure the user signed in again? Without that, they may have to wait for up to an hour before their auth session picks up the updated verification state. Alternatively you can call `user.getIdToken(true)` (or `user.reload()`) to force a refresh of that token.

Comment: I’m positive. I checked the console. User reload is only for signed in users. 
If I refresh the page it works fine. Is there a way to refresh an angular component without refreshing the page?

Comment: SendVerificationMail() {
    this.ngFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      user.sendEmailVerification();

    });
  }

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 's suggestion should work just fine. All you need to refesh the token. Angular component can be refeshed by routing to a dummy route and coming back to inital working page or by adding an ngIf over the component selector if need be. 

But in Ideal case this is not necessary. And can looking creepy on UX.

Comment: the suggestion does not work